# Accessing Class Variables from a List in a nice way in Python

Tags: python, class, list, dictionary, methods

Suppose I have a list X = [a, b, c]  where a, b, c are instances of the same class C.
Now,  all these instances a,b,c,  have a variable called v,   a.v,  b.v, c.v ...
I simply want a list  Y =  [a.v, b.v, c.v]

Is there a nice command to do this? 
The best way I can think of is:

```
Y = []
for i in X
    Y.append(i.v)
```

But it doesn't seem very elegant ~ since this needs to be repeated for any given "v"
Any suggestions? I couldn't figure out a way to use "map" to do this.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

That should work:

```
Y = [x.v for x in X]
```

Answer (score 5):

The list comprehension is the way to go.

But you also said you don't know how to use map to do it. Now, I would not *recommend* to use `map` for this at all, but it can be done:

```
map( lambda x: x.v, X)
```

that is, you create an anonymous function (a lambda) to return that attribute.

If you prefer to use the python library methods (know thy tools...) then something like:

```
map(operator.attrgetter("v"),X)
```

should also work.

Comment: @Deniz I think it's fair to award the answer to FlorianH as he really has the best solution in this case, and was first with the answer. My answer was more intended to show alternative ways, and to show how to use map in this case.

Comment: 2 things I thought after reading the question were, definitely `map` .. ah wait how about `itemgetter`. +1 for you.

Answer (score 2):

I would do a list comprehension:

```
Y = [ i.v for i in X ]
```

It is shorter and more conveniant.